# How make bracketSameLine: true work with prettier in intellij Ultimate?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, prettier, brackets

Prettier does not leave brackets on same line.
This is annoying for me and people who check my code as it is poor readability.
Example below :

[image]
[image]

I use Intellij Ultimate version 2023.2.2.
I work on an Angular project.

**Settings**

[image]

**.prettierrc.json**

```
{
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

Comment: Does it work correctly if you run prettier in the command line (and not in the IDE)?
It looks related to https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/11484

Comment: @Oksana: it finally start working for html. No more floating tags (even without htmlWhitespaceSensitivity). I can't explain why so I leave this question open for now.
Thanks for the reply